# View not loading xib file when pushed from navigation controller

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've been struggling over this for a while, sifting through solutions online but haven't managed to get there so I figured it was about time to ask you wonderful folk. I have a tab bar application in which I am trying to use a navigation controller containing a table view (`TableViewController`) to switch to different views depending on the cell that is pressed.

When touching a cell in the table view my `SecondViewController` is loaded (this is working as I checked by colouring the background in the `viewDidLoad()` method) however the interface (`XIB`) is not loading and thus the window is blank (or coloured in the case of my background test). The window (`SecondViewController`) is supposed to contain a `UIScrollerView` which works when accessing the view directly. I should mention that all the view controllers are contained within a single `XIB` file and the `XIB` file contains the tab bar controller and a blank window required by the App Delegate (window and `tabBarController`).

This is how I switch views from `TableViewController.m` (`rootViewController` of `navigationController`)

```
SecondViewController *viewSecond = [SecondViewController alloc];
self.secondViewController = viewSecond;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.secondViewController animated:YES];
```

This is the `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions()` in `appDelegate.m`

```
// Set the tab bar controller as the window's root view controller and display.
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;  
return YES;
```

This was actually a follow on from an old project so I'm now sure why the blank window is required in the `XIB` (if that has anything to do with the problem) as it is not required in the template tab bar application. I've only just started iOS development so I apologize if I'm vague anywhere. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In your `TableViewController.m`, you have missed to `init` your `SecondViewController`. Just calling `alloc` doesn't load from nib.

So change 
 `SecondViewController *viewSecond = [SecondViewController alloc];` 
into 
`SecondViewController *viewSecond = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];` 
or 
`SecondViewController *viewSecond = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];`

Comment: I added the init in the code but the same problem occurs. I have used the `NSLog` to print out the value of the nib name of  `SecondViewController` which returned `null`. I used the second section of code you gave that uses the `initWithNibName` function and the application terminated with `NSInternalInconsistencyException reason: Could not load NIB in bundle`. I am assuming that's the reason the 'SecondViewController' is not loading the nib when being accessed through the `TableViewController.m`. Any idea where I've left something out that allocates the nib for the view controllers? Cheers

Comment: Check the name of `xib` file. Is it `SecondViewController.xib`? Check if there is spelling mistake in name of this file.

Comment: No your assumption is not correct. It should load from `TableViewController.m`, if it exists in the project

Comment: All my view controllers are contained within a single .xib file `MainWindow` (not my greatest design layout...). Shouldn't it therefore load with `[[SecondViewController alloc] init];`?

Comment: (clap) Sorry, from hereon I can't help you because I haven't used this design layout. May be someone else here could help you. You may also consider creating separate xib files for all of your view controllers. This will be much easier for you to handle this problem.